# Qt4 problem with formatting hours in QDateTime

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qdatetime

I've a problem with following code:

```
QDateTime test2;
test2.setTime_t(25);
qDebug() << test2.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

this prints "01:00:25" to output instead of 00:00:25.
Why is the first hour set to 01 instead of 00 ?

I thought that maybe am/pm notation is used so i tried this

```
QDateTime test2;
test2.setTime_t(3600*22+25);
qDebug() << test2.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

And still i received on output

"23:00:25"

Help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you didn't set the QDateTime to UTC.  So, 00:00:25 on Jan 1st 1970 in UTC time was probably 01:00:25 in your local timezone?  And your code says "10:00:25" for me, at UTC+10 :)

Try this:

```
QDateTime test2;
test2.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);    
test2.setTime_t(25);
qDebug() << test2.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work :(. I tried all three options in setTimeSpec and hour is either 01 or 03. Maybe I have to set some other option ?

Comment: Did you use _exactly_ the code I pasted?  If you e.g. put "AP" in your time string then that shifts the formatting from using 0-23 for hours, to using 1-12.

Comment: Ok I see the problem. This line test2.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC); has to be put before test2.setTime_t(25); Works fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, it seems UTC is messing with you. Check the last line of the output:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv );

    QDateTime test1;
    test1.setTime_t(25);
    qDebug() << "Local 1: " << test1.toString("hh:mm:ss");
    qDebug() << "Local 1: " << test1.toString();
    qDebug() << "UTC   1: " << test1.toUTC().toString();

    QDateTime test2;
    test2.setDate(QDate(1970,01,01));
    test2.setTime(QTime(00,59));
    qDebug() << "Local 2: " << test2.toString("hh:mm:ss");
    qDebug() << "Local 2: " << test2.toString();
    qDebug() << "UTC   2: " << test2.toUTC().toString();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Local 1:  "01:00:25" 
Local 1:  "Thu Jan 1 01:00:25 1970" 
UTC   1:  "Thu Jan 1 00:00:25 1970" 
Local 2:  "00:59:00" 
Local 2:  "Thu Jan 1 00:59:00 1970" 
UTC   2:  "Wed Dec 31 23:59:00 1969"
```

PS: I'm at UTC + 1